# EF Core: How can I sort items in scaffolded drop-down lists?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, crud

I have a model class definition as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace NewProject
{
    public partial class Institutions
    {
        public int InstitutionID { get; set; }    
        public string InstitutionName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<NotificationOfChangePage> NotificationOfChangePage{ get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SuspensionOrTerminationPage> SuspensionOrTerminationPage{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Later on when I use EF core to scaffold a NotificationOfChangePageor a SuspensionOrTerminationPage (which are dependent on the Institutions model), the dropdown lists that appear on the Create/Edit pages are ordered by InstitutionID - how can I make them actually ordered by InstitutionName ? Is this something that I would handle in the actual View?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @Jake where do collect the data? please post relevant code where you use EF to fetch records from database.

Comment: Why don't you use Linq orderby extension while calling Institutions. example, context.Institutions.orderby(x=>x.InstitutionName).

Comment: Nick B - where would context.Institutions generally be called? I'm not super familiar with EF core or .net core so I'm not super confident in my ability to explain my issue. Sorry about the ambiguous question above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nick B's comment led me to the correct answer. In the page's controller, the following bit of code is generated via scaffolding:

```
ViewData["InstitutionID"] = new SelectList(_context.Institutions, "InstitutionID", "InstitutionName");
```

I had to append .OrderBy(x => x.Text) to this to get:

```
ViewData["InstitutionID"] = new SelectList(_context.Institutions, "InstitutionID", "InstitutionName")**.OrderBy(x => x.Text)**;
```

Now the dropdown list shows the Institutions in alphabetical order.